# Cordova Ionic 2 WKWebView hide scroll bars

Tags: cordova, ionic2, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to remove all scrollbars from my ionic 2 app using the WKWebView

I can hide them with css using the standard webview, but when using the WKWebView it does not work.

I have tried editing the CDVWKWebviewEngine.m file with the following but had no luck

`wkWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
wkWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
[wkWebView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[wkWebView.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
wkWebView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30000, 0,  0, 10);`

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I'm developing an app with Cordova and stuck with the same problem.

Comment: my solution was to have a wrapping div that covers the screen with overflow:hidden and the child scrolling div at width 110% and 10%padding right causing the scroll indicators to be off screen

Comment: no native fix unfortunately

Comment: Anyone ever found a solution? I am still searching.